# Why does Django Rest Framework add a slash on my URL when i filter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm just getting started to Django Rest Framework and i created my first endpoints. Now, i'm trying to add filtering to my URLS but there are two things i don't understand yet:

1. I created the following route: `router.register(r'endpoint', views.myView, basename='myView')`.
   When i try to filter on my browser like the following `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/endpoint?&user=TEST`, i will get redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/endpoint/?&user=TEST`. Why is there a slash before the `?`?
2. What is the difference between using `router.register` and a standard view on my `urlpatterns` like i would do in Django?

Comment: There's a Django setting that controls whether it appends a slash to URLs or not: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#append-slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because the default value of  [**`APPEND_SLASH`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) is **`True`** and hence the redirection.
2. The [DRF routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) will generate ***appropriate URL patterns*** depending on which type of router
   ([SimpleRouter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) or [DefaultRouter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) ) you are using. Highy recommend using along with the [DRF ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, it's very clear. What happens if i set APPEND_SLASH to False? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: I would like to set the `APPEND_SLASH=True` (the default setup) and I would *not* define any end-points without a *trailing slash*